# Excel return value under string searched

Tags: excel

I'm looking at a way to search a value in a column and return the value of the cell under the cell containing the string searched.

For exemple,

Search ABC in this column :

- XYZ
- DSK
- KDE
- ABC
- EFL
- EKQ

The function would return EFL

The cell position of ABC isn't known. So this doesn't work :

```
IF(A1:A6="ABC";A5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MATCH`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) and [`INDEX`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/index-HP005209138.aspx) is your friend

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ABC",A:A,0)+1)
```

you should also probably add a check to see that the data is in the range, as you will get an error with the above function if `ABC` doesn't exist

You can use `COUNTIF` for this

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"ABC")>0,INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ABC",A:A,0)+1),"")
```

Comment: `MATCH("ABC",A:A)` results in #N/A for me...If you put in `MATCH("ABC",A:A,0)` for exact match it works... +1

Comment: I added that into the answer, it did work fine for me without the `,0` in testing though...

Comment: It worked for 0 and -1 for me but for 1 and default I got NA...[If match_type is omitted, it is assumed to be 1.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-HP005209168.aspx) So it would depend on the order of the text

Comment: Well it looks like `0` is probably the right type to use in this instance anyway. So thank you for the heads up :)

Comment: Even with the values sorted 0 is best because that's the only one that guarantees an exact match